# Parsing the package error while downloading Obj file

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I was searching for parsing package error on stackoverflow but most of them are related to apk file download. My problem is slightly different because I am trying to download .obj file instead of .apk. The process I followed is:-

1. Using download manager to download .obj file from url.
2. Storing .obj
   file inside sdcard folder which I have created using my app.
3. After
   download done successfully it seems download manager is trying to
   open the file and I am getting this parsing package error.

How I can stop download manager to open the file on download complete automatically? Or Is it possible to open Obj file with "Emb3D" app which is already installed on my device?

Any help would be much obliged.[image]

Comment: I faced this issue past 4 years back. Your testing device is not compatible with this apk. And do update ur version number and code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is not related to apk file. I am downloading .Obj file.